# Unknown Wi-Fi SSID detected - is it a danger?

Tags: wifi

I see an available connection "Eliza" in my area. How can I check if this is a danger to me?

Comment: Are you connecting to "Eliza" or is it just a random SSID that is being picked up (from you neighbor for example)?

Comment: Unless your local newspaper has recently been writing about new modern-day [serial killer going by name Eliza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lizzie_Halliday), there is no danger to you. It just means that your neighbor got themselves a WiFi Internet and decided to name it "Eliza" instead of leaving default name to "Linksys17DA4E98" or whatever. Though, when you get a lot of them around you, it might cause a degradation of your wifi quality. But with just a few (especially one!) it is not an issue at all.

Comment: Seeing it is no danger, connecting to it could be dangerous.  Although it is mostly likely another regular persons wifi, some people have setup AP that monitor and/or steal the data you access.

Comment: That depends: [is it asking you questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA)?

Answer (score 19):

Most WiFi networks announce their names. I’m living in a small village, so I see five around me. Someone living in an apartment block reported he saw 37! And the people using these networks will also see the name of your network.

Unless you connect to this network named “Eliza” nobody on that network can read your data. And to connect, you would need the password for that network. Assuming that you are connected to your own network, nobody not connected to your network can read your data. If someone is connected to your network, data is encrypted but depending on the security someone could be able to decrypt it.

So if your network doesn’t have high security, don’t give anyone your password. And tell all users not to give anyone their password.

Summary: Seeing unknown WiFi networks is normal and harmless.

Comment: Or, put another way, it's not the wifi access points that are a danger, it's the wifi clients that are.\

Comment: Everybody gangsta until the Street View car passes looking to ***"meet hot single Access Points in your area"*** and cross-reference that with their other less-morally-obtained databases then sells the bulk data to the FBI without a warrant. What a tax rebate!

Comment: It would probably be dangerous to connect to that "Eliza" network, assuming they left is as an open-wifi, without password. Then they could steal passwords in case you access websites without https. Here is a random article I found about this:  https://www.lifewire.com/is-it-safe-to-use-an-open-wireless-network-2378210

Comment: The exclamation mark after the second sentence made me laugh so hard. Thank you. (That said, I count fewer than 37 unless I count those that are on both 2.4 and 5GHz twice.)

Comment: Just counted... 97 SSID's (and half of them on both 2.4 and 5 GHz bands and not counting the 4 SSID's from our own company). Office building surrounded by 6 apartment high-rises in busy city. And at some point last year there were 135. Needless to say that without special measures inside our own building Wifi is useless. We have special mesh wall-paper on the out-side walls and coating on the windows that act as Wifi reflectors, keeping most of the external signal out.

Answer (score 0):

The risk here is that if you connect to it, the Access Point (AP) might allow other people to scan your system using Nmap etc.

If you don't know who's running an AP, and haven't been explicitly authorised to connect to it, then it's best left alone. In fact if you've not been explicitly authorised to connect to it it might be illegal to do so, depending on your jurisdiction.

If it's left alone, you're safe. But you might have a lot of fun working out who owns it, and which literary allusion they're making :-)

Noting what other people have said: with the aid of a couple of cocoa cans on a tripod I detected around 37 APs over a 120 degree arc. I'm careful with my security, and don't lose any sleep over them.